# How can I use matplotlib.pyplot.xticks or similar when using subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, ticker

I'd like to manipulate the ticks of every plot in my subplots. When plotting a single plot I get the desired result by using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# ...
# some data acquisition
# ...

ax.imshow(data[i], cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin='bottom')
ax.contour(x, y, dataFitted[i].reshape(2*crop, 2*crop), 3, colors='white')

# adjust scale from pixel to micrometers on heat maps
pixelSize = 5.5 # micrometer/pxl
scaleEnd = crop * pixelSize
wishedTicks = np.array([-150, -100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150])
originalTicks = (wishedTicks + scaleEnd) / pixelSize

plt.xticks(originalTicks, wishedTicks)
plt.yticks(originalTicks, wishedTicks)
```

So far, so good, but if I use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=4)
```

to create subplots, the function `plt.xticks()` is not available any more to my understanding.

Is there a way to receive the same result by

- either globally (for all figures) manipulating the axis in the same way I did for a single plot

or

- manipulating each subplot individually in the desired way as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always work with an explicit axes, for plotting, as for setting the ticks/labels.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,4, figsize=(9,7))

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.plot(...)
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `plt.subplot` [(documentation)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) instead of `plt.subplots` might suit your needs.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
x_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k']
y = np.arange(0, 20, 2)

for i in range(1, 5):
        ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.xticks(x, x_labels)

plt.show()
```

Produces this:
[image: output]

Also recommend reading [this article on subplots](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.08-multiple-subplots.html) to see some more neat stuff you can do with them.

Comment: Thanks, it worked so far. Can you tell me if it is possible to increase the figure size for all subplots, as everything is crunched together tightly. I did only find solutions where one has an attributed figure object like e.g. f, ax = fig.subplots(a, b, figsize(1,1)).

Comment: `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)` should work. You can play with the values.

Comment: but @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's answer is probably better. I just didn't remember how to do that explicitly with the axes (`.xticks` didn't work)

Comment: you can try plt.tight_layout() and see if it improves the spacing between the subplots